# How to check event is already exist for a day - fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

How to check event is already exist for a day while using `renderEvent` method.

I have found may answer in in stack for `dayClick` with `clientEvents`, I am not sure how it use for `renderEvent`.

```
var diffDay = 5; 
for (var i = 0; i < diffDay; i++) {
    var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
    var newDay = new Date(event.start);
    copiedEventObject.start = newDay;
    $inlineCalendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);                       
}
```

I am looking a if condition like below or any other solution

```
if(....Condition?....){
    $inlineCalendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);                       
}
```

Comment: Any one have answer for this question...???

Answer (score 0):

My solution is compare the .start of EventObject.

**Update: after discussion, seems we had opposite understanding before, I update my code**

So the Condition at my solution is:

```
var allevents = $inlineCalendar.fullCalendar( 'clientEvents');

for(var i=0;i<allevents.length;i++ ){
var currentevent=allevents[i];
if((
(copiedEventObject.allDay && copiedEventObject.start == currentevent.start) 
|| HasSameDate(currentevent.start,copiedEventObject.start)
) == false){
    $inlineCalendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);                       
}
}

function HasSameDate(date1,date2)
{
   return $inlineCalendar.fullCalendar.formatDate(date1, 'yyyyMMdd') == $inlineCalendar.fullCalendar.formatDate(date2, 'yyyyMMdd');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick replay, I'll test you answer soon and make it acceptable if its for me.

Comment: Currently its not working for me, always invoking to else case, I am checking if any error from my side, also can you specify me what you meant "currentevent.start"

Comment: I have tried out your updated code, but its always getting else case.

Comment: So interesting! It works at my side. Seems my answer has 5 votes, not sure if work at their side. By the way, what errors at your side?

Comment: Its always getting else case and found condition result like this "true : Wed May 14 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) : undefined : false". It means "currentevent.start" is undefined.

Comment: So interesting... What are the value of allevents and the 1st currentevent?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52254/discussion-between-jaison-and-billy-yeah)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately above answer is not working in my scenario. So I found one solution from my own way. May it will help someone, but not sure its a right way.

```
var allevents = $inlineCalendar.fullCalendar('clientEvents');
                var arrAlleventsDate = [];

                for(i in allevents){
                    if(arrAlleventsDate.indexOf($.fullCalendar.formatDate(allevents[i].start, 'yyyyMMdd')) == -1){
                        arrAlleventsDate.push($.fullCalendar.formatDate(allevents[i].start, 'yyyyMMdd'));
                    }
                }
if(arrAlleventsDate.indexOf($.fullCalendar.formatDate(newDay, 'yyyyMMdd')) == -1){
                        $inlineCalendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true); 
                    }
```

If you wish work for each event, add event id as a prefix for date.

Answer (score 0):

In agenda-view, I check in "select" if there are others event in the selected period; the cheks is on limit number, a field (es: title or custom field) and time period:

```
 select: function(start, end, jsEvent) {
   var maxEvent = 2;
   var allEvents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'clientEvents');
   var xst = moment(start);
   var xen = moment(end);
   var eventsCount = 0;
   var collideEvent;
   var tempField;
   for(var i=0;i<allEvents.length;i++ ) {
     var currentEvent=allEvents[i];
     if(xst.isBetween(currentevent.start,currentevent.end,null, '[)') || 
        xen.isBetween(currentevent.start,currentevent.end,null, '(]')) {
         eventsCount++;
         if(eventsCount>=maxEvent && tempField != currentEvent.field) {
           alert("!");
           $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
           return false;
           break;
         }
         collideEvent = currentEvent;
         tempField = collideEvent.field;                                
      }
   //proceed!
}
```